# Bootstrap CSS aligning a division class

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code in the Bootstrap Mini CSS. The column in question is `col-md4`

```
.col-md-1,.col-md-2,.col-md-3,.col-md-4,.col-md-5,.col-md-6,.col-md-7,.col-md-8,.col-md-9,.col-md-10,.col-md-11,.col-md-12 {
    float: left;
}

.col-md-12 {
    width: 100%;
}

.col-md-11 {
    width: 91.66666667%;
}

.col-md-10 {
    width: 83.33333333%;
}

.col-md-9 {
    width: 75%;
}

.col-md-8 {
    width: 66.66666667%;
}

.col-md-7 {
    width: 58.33333333%;
}

.col-md-6 {
    width: 50%;
}

.col-md-5 {
    width: 41.66666667%;
}

.col-md-4 {
    width: 380px;
}

.container-fluid .row .col-md-4.side-bar.text-default {
}
```

So I have width set at 380px. Where would I put the `align-right`? Or right margin to say 0?

I cannot align it to the right of the screen. There is an ugly gap between the the right margin. I'm sort of new to Bootstrap, but I cannot align this to the right try as I may.

Right margin gap:

[image: Right margin gap]

Comment: Can you shear your html code snippet also with us it will then easy for us to figure out what's going on there?

Comment: Sure of course....<div class="col-md-4 side-bar text-default"> </div>

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap columns have a `padding` of `15px` by default.

You can remove this padding if you like, but you **should not** be changing bootstrap file, even less changing one of its column classes to a fixed width.

You can see the padding here:

```css
.container > div {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellowgreen;
}
.container > div:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: lime;
}
.content {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}
.container > div::after {
  font-size: .8em;
  content: "padding";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: rotateZ(270deg);
  transform-origin: top left;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<main class="container">
  <div class="col-xs-8">
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
</main>
```

---

The best approach is to use an utility class on a separate CSS file.

```css
.container > div {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellowgreen;
}
.container > div:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: lime;
}
.content {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}
.container > div:not(.col--no-padding)::after {
  font-size: .8em;
  content: "padding";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: rotateZ(270deg);
  transform-origin: top left;
}
.col--no-padding {
  /*
     Will use !important for code snippet illustration purposes.
     Your file should be referenced AFTER Bootstrap.
  */
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<main class="container">
  <div class="col-xs-8">
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 col--no-padding">
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Thank you so much I will try this!

Comment: OK tried that it seems like there is a layer or mask I now get the padding in between the map and side nav bar. https://pokefindernow.com/test/testing_page.html I have checked the elements but cannot find where to add or remove the padding...any help would be appreciated? Essentially I just want to show the map right up to the right colum.